# Artefacts when using geom_sf and projection

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps, r-sf

I want to plot a simple world map with the mercator projection using `geom_sf()` in `ggplot`:

```
library(maps)
library(sf)

# Load world map and transform to Mercator projection
world1 <- sf::st_as_sf(map('world', plot = FALSE, fill = TRUE))

# Plot the map using ggplot and sf
world1 %>%
  filter(ID != "Antarctica") %>%
  ggplot() + 
  geom_sf() +
  coord_sf(crs = st_crs("EPSG:3857"))
```

However, this leads to this very weird plot, where some countries (like Russia) have lines through the whole plot:
[image]

This does not happen when I remove the transformation or filter out the country (like Russia). Any idea why this happens and how to fix it?

Comment: not so much an answer as a way around it, using the pseudomercator epsg google map uses (4326) does not produce those artefacts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The artefact you describe is related to the fact that Russia crosses the antimeridian. The 180 degrees line lies mainly in the ocean, but Chukotka peninsula in Russia and two islands of Fiji archipelago cross it.

The world dataset in `{maps}` is, like the package itself, sort of dated. It contains 5 invalid objects, leading to all sorts of mishaps.

```r
sf::st_as_sf(map('world', plot = FALSE, fill = TRUE)) %>% 
  sf::st_is_valid() %>% 
  table()
```

Since the use case for a world map is very, very common there are a number of standard solutions around; my suggestion would therefore be to do a Marie Kondo on the `{maps}` package: thank it for a long service (did you know it originally comes from Richard A. Becker & Allan R. Wilks [and is a few months older than R itself](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/2684060_Maps_in_S)?) and let it go.

You will be better served by more modern instances of the world dataset; my suggestion would be the one that lives in `{giscoR}` package. It is based on geodata by GISCO (the GIS arm of Eurostat) and is known to be both current and spatially valid.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(sf)

# Load world map and transform to Mercator projection
world1 <- giscoR::gisco_get_countries()

# Plot the map using ggplot and sf
world1 %>%
  dplyr::filter(NAME_ENGL != "Antarctica") %>%
  ggplot() + 
  geom_sf() +
  coord_sf(crs = st_crs("EPSG:3857"))
```

[image]