Trying to replicate a map with Mercater-type projection dimensions
I've been struggling to recreate this map with ggplot and would be super appreciative of any input. My main issue is in capturing the 2D aspect ratio.
Intended map

Basic issue
The closest I've come
library(maps)
library(ggplot2)
world <- map_data("world")
ggplot(world, aes(long, lat, group = group)) +
  geom_polygon() +
  coord_map(xlim = c(-180, 180), ylim = c(-52, 83.6))

This outputs something pretty close, but it's clipping the top of the map and I can't seem to undo it!
Output of code

Can someone please save me. I've been at this for like 15 hours without any luck.

Use coord_sf() instead of the superseded coord_map() for better results.

This answer looks like it produces something pretty similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75985111/artefacts-when-using-geom-sf-and-projection
